# How much storage and bandwidth do I need for hosting an online store?

Tags: storage, hosting, web-hosting, bandwidth

How much bandwidth and storage do I need to store a small online shop, with let's say 200-250 products and how should I know how many visitors my site has monthly? Can you give me some real example, in order to make myself an idea? If you already have an online store or already existing online stores (Stradivarius, Zara, something smaller?)
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

1. Domain name - pays yearly ~ $10-40 (reasonable).
2. Web hosting - pays monthly ~ $3-10.
   I wouldn't worry about disk space and traffic. For example some hosters give 50GB space + Unlimited traffic for ~$6/mo.
3. Shop engine - mostly free, 50 - 250 MBytes space. Generally your products require MySQL database space, which is commonly sufficient for your store size in hosting plans priced in part 2.

   - WooCommerce, PrestaShop and OpenCart will require less space,
   - Monsters like magento will require more space.
4. Statistics - To monitor bandwidth you can use [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com).
5. SEO - if your web store is not popular, there is no point in having it.

If you are a startup you can first leverage free online shopping platforms like ebay, and later trouble yourself with self hosted web shop.

P.S. Estimations on traffic are 1-2MB / per page. If we assume 25% cache hits for images (user should see new content every other link), and interest rate like 7 products per user.
We can very roughly estimate, that one user produce ~11MB of traffic. I.e. 1.1GB per 100 users.
P.P.S. If you optimize content it will be significantly less.